# How to make a discord bot mention a user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am now making a discord bot and want to make a poke command. The user can poke another member. I know how to mention the author but I cannot seem to mention the user. EXAMPLE: '!poke [user given by the author]'.

How do I make my bot mention that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `user.toString()`. For example:

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {

    if(message.content.startsWith("poke")){
        let userToMention = message.mentions.users.first();
        message.channel.send("Mention: "+userToMention.toString());
    }

});
```

If you write `!poke @user`, the bot will reply with `Mention: @user`.